# how to update data in database table

Tags: magento2, database, collection, duplicate

I am sending data to the database by checking duplicate data. But I can't be inserting/updating data in the database.

```
protected function saveEntityFinish(array $entityData, $table) {
        $collection= $this->PostTableFactory->create();
        $item = $collection->getCollection();


        if ($entityData) {
            $tableName = $this->_connection->getTableName($table);
            $entityIn = [];
            $entityInup = [];
            foreach ($entityData as $id => $entityRows) {
                    foreach ($entityRows as $row) {
                        $item->addFieldToFilter('rule_id',$row['rule_id']);
                        $item->addFieldToFilter('store_id',$row['store_id']);

                        if(count($item->getData()) == 0){
                            $temp= $item->getData();
                            $logger->info('one');
                            $collection->setRuleId($row['rule_id']);
                            $collection->setStoreId($row['store_id']);
                            $collection->setStatus($row['status']);
                            $entityIn[] = $row;
                            $collection->save();
                        }else{
                            $entityInup = $row;


                            $collection = $this->PostTableFactory->create();
                            $collection->load($item->getData()[0]['p_id']);

                            $collection->setRuleId($entityInup['rule_id']);
                            $collection->setStoreId($entityInup['store_id']);
                            $collection->setStatus($entityInup['status']);
                            $entityIn[] = $entityInup;
                            $collection->save();

                        }

                    }
            }


        }
        return $this;
    }
```

can I get help on it? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update a row we have to add that **column id** attached with updated data in that row will update the row

Answer (score 0):

I have updated my value using CollectionFactory. You can give it a try

```
 $query = $this->_YourCollection->create()
                ->addFieldToFilter('field_id', $value)
                ->addFieldToFilter('filed',$value2)->getFirstItem();
            if ($query->getData()){
                if ($yourCondition){
                    $query->setData('field','valuefor update');
                    $query->save();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thank you @Ghulam.M for responce, this filter method showing invalid